# PostgreSQL date value changes to next day after 5 PM PST

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime

Whenever I create data after 5 PM PST (Pacific Standard Time), the `manufactured_date` column gets changed to next date.

For example, I entered new data today which is `2020-11-05` at `5:15 pm PST`, the value that gets stored in `manufactured_date` column is `2020-10-06`

Query `select * from cars` gives me below result

```
id | car_name | manufactured_date
---------------------------------
1  | Audi     | 11-06-2020
2  | BMW      | 11-06-2020
```

Here are the properties of `cars` table

```
column name       | data type
-----------------------------
id                | serial
car_name          | varchar
manufactured_date | date
```

The `insert` query is

```
insert
    into
    cars (car_name, manufactured_date)
values ('Audi', '11-05-2020');
```

How can I eliminate this problem?

Comment: Please include the INSERT/UPDATE statement that you used in order to enter the date value.

Comment: @JonathanJacobson Updated the question with insert statement.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the `cars` table that is touching the `manufactured_date` field? In psql what does  `SHOW timezone` return?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when (now() now() at time zone 'PST')::time >= '17:00:00'::time
             then manufactured_date + interval '1 day'
             else manufactured_date
        end)
```

Comment: The problem is that, the `date` value (in `manufactured_date` column) which is being stored as tomorrow's date instead of today's date

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the server is running in UTC and that is column is based on UTC instead of PST timezone.

to validate this you can just execute this and it should return the current timestamp according to server timezone:

```
select now()
```

Comment: That makes sense. Would we be able to store `date` values irrespective of timezones? In my case, the `manufactured_date` column. So that the date won't get incremented to tomorrow's date.

Comment: How do you set manufactured_date when you insert new values?

Comment: I'm using moment.js to get the current date and formatting it to `MM-DD-YYYY` string.

Comment: I guess before formatting you should convert the time zone to PST, i.e. in Postgres you could use `select now(),now() AT time zone 'PST';`

Comment: Have you checked the Postgres log to see if the  date string is actually just `MM-DD_YYYY` and that it is not being sent over with a time zone?

Comment: @scriobh I would recommend to check momentum.js if the timezone is set there (and the conversion is done correctly) - see https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/ . I think the problem is rather there than in postgres as you already just hand over a date if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is really interesting! I couldn't reproduce your problem on my VM, even after playing with the OS time-zone settings and with the `PGTZ` environment variable.

Can you please try not counting on implicit data type conversions? Adding the `DATE` directive before what is currently a string literal might help:

```
INSERT INTO cars (car_name, manufactured_date)
VALUES ('Audi', DATE '2020-11-05');
```

Comment: I'm actually inserting data using an API. In that, I'm using moment.js to get the current date and formatting that date to `MM-DD-YYYY`

Comment: P.S. Could be because of the way that you wrote the string representation of the date. Always use the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: So is it a bind variable or are you building the SQL dynamically?

Comment: I even tried with `YYYY-MM-DD` it still gives the same result. ( Tomorrow's date )

Comment: Building SQL dynamically

Comment: That's not a good practice. Use a bind variable. If you must use dynamic SQL then try the `DATE` directive as suggested, and change the formatting to `YYYY-MM-DD`.